# Junit for Class with local variable loading beans

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I have class which is having a class level variable where it is trying to load a bean, something like:
Beanx beanx =  ApplicationContext.getBean("beanName")

while am trying to write junit for this, am getting nullPointerException, as it is trying to load the above bean first.
How can I write JUnit for such class?

Comment: use mockito to mock `ApplicationContext`

Comment: can you share any sample . I tried but no luck

Comment: First you have to share your Junit class with what you have tried so far.

Comment: Why is the class directly accessing `ApplicationContext`?  Can the actual bean not be injected through the constructor?

Comment: thats how it has been desingned. Since its a legacy code, we dont want to change the architecture rather add Unit Test coverage

Comment: Then as @pleft already said you need to mock `ApplicationContext`, there is no other way.